# how to substitute from a string to multiple patterns using awk/sed?

Tags: awk, sed, xargs

I have a patternfile.txt.

```
1 FPAT = "pata"
2 FPAT = "patb"
3 FPAT = "patc"
```

and a awkfile.txt.

```
BEGIN { FPAT }
{
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){
       print("%s\n", $i)}
 }
```

I want to make multiple files after substitute a string 'FPAT' to each patterns pata, patb, patc one by one like these.

1. awkfile1.txt :

   ```
   BEGIN { FPAT = "pata" }
   {
      for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){
          print("%s\n", $i)}
   }
   ```
2. awkfile2.txt :

   ```
   BEGIN { FPAT = "patb" }
   {
       for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){
           print("%s\n", $i)}
    }
   ```
3. awkfile3.txt :

   ```
   BEGIN { FPAT = "patc" }
   {
        for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){
            print("%s\n", $i)}
   }
   ```

   Please help me.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to do. What is your desired output?

Comment: Do you know that `FPAT` is a gawk builtin variable name? Is that really what you're trying to modify? If not, this is why you shouldn't name your variable all upper-case, to avoid clashes with built in variable names you may not even know exist.

Answer (score 2):

I've got a feeling that this is a bit of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) but I think you can get the output you're looking for in one invocation of awk:

```
awk '{ print "BEGIN { " substr($0, index($0, $2)) " }" > ("awkfile" $1 ".txt") }' patternfile.txt
```

This simply reads each line of the input file and produces the writes the part you're interested in (from the second field to the end of the line) to the output file. It uses the first field of the input to determine the output file name.

Comment: @BBungBBung : Welcome to StackOverflow. Be sure to accept and/or upvote answers that help you. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235 . Good luck.

Comment: Definately this answer is so helpful. But I'm still having a problem to read the remaining part of original awkfile except BEGIN part.

Comment: It's a shame that you've totally changed your input since I wrote my answer :/

Comment: Sorry, Tom French. To clarify my point I changed. Thank you for your answer. I became more aware of the things that you gave comments.